# Как посмотреть вывод процесса

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

ssh завершился pipe brocken. Но процесс команды не остановился `apt-get install mongodb` что видно по команде `ps axjf | grep apt-get`. Так вот вопрос, как вывести вывод процесса в фоне в текущий терминал? Вопрос решился частично тем что процесс отработал, но всё равно интересно как сделать вывод процесса в фоне в текущий терминал.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тот вопрос о том как направить вывод в фаил в лесс и т.д. мой вопрос как возобновить вывод в текущий терминал... Прочитайте плиз я пишу выше, что выбросило из ssh но процесс остался работать в фоне. Я залогинился заново по ssh, так вот как вывод процесса в фоне в каком то другом терминале направить в тот в котором я сейчас нахожусь.

Comment: ответ на вопрос, ссылку на который я привёл, подходит и в качестве ответа на ваш вопрос. но вообще ответов на подобные вопросы можно дать очень много. и все подойдут. посмотрите ответы к вопросам: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1323956/4827341 http://stackoverflow.com/q/249703/4827341 http://superuser.com/q/473240/454489

Comment: На будущее - запускай все комманды внутри `tmux` или `screen`. В ссылках выше наверняка об это кто-нибудь, да упомянул.

Comment: @donRumata `screen` это ясно. А вот без `screen` и `tmux` в ссылках выше на русский СО ответа нет.

Comment: Через `bg` и `fg` пробовал?

Comment: @donRumata как будет обрыв ssh попробую а так нет не пробывал.